# TRANSFORM and PIVOT in Access 2013 SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, ms-access-2013

How can I get second table from first table using TRANSFORM and PIVOT functions:

TABLE_01

```
Config_ID  |  ConfigField  |  ConfigValue
-----------------------------------------
       11  |         Name  |        Basic
       11  |      Version  |         1.01
       11  |        Owner  |         Jack
       12  |         Name  |     Advanced
       12  |      Version  |         1.03
       12  |        Owner  |         Andy
```

TABLE_02

```
Config_ID  |      Name  |  Version  |  Owner
--------------------------------------------
       11  |     Basic  |     1.01  |  Jack
       12  |  Advanced  |     1.03  |  Andy
```

I'm trying this:

```
TRANSFORM ConfigValue
SELECT Config_ID
FROM TABLE_01
GROUP BY Config_ID
PIVOT ConfigField
```

but got an error:

> "Your query does not include the specified expression 'ACValue' as part
>   of aggregate function."

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I have found solution by myself:

```
TRANSFORM FIRST(ConfigValue)
SELECT Config_ID
FROM TABLE_01
GROUP BY Config_ID
PIVOT ConfigField
```

Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: I've no idea why you posted this and accepted it instead of the answer that told you that you were missing an aggregate function 9 days previously.

Answer (score 51):

It looks like you are missing the aggregate function in the TRANSFORM:

```
TRANSFORM Max(ConfigValue)
SELECT Config_ID
FROM TABLE_01
GROUP BY Config_ID
PIVOT ConfigField
```