# Match columns with a sub query and return query as column?

Tags: sql, ms-access

So write now I have two types of data in my DB Table "forecast" data and "Actual" data all the field for these rows are the same except for the 'Type' Field that indicates whether the data is a "forcast" or Actual and the Quantity field.

What I need to do is determine the accuracy of the forecast by dividing the matching Rows Quantity Field. T

So I would have this

**Table Orders**

```
Order No.   Delivery Date   Quantity(cases)     Type
1234         6/20/2014           100            Forecast
1234         6/20/2014            70            Actual
```

Then do a query that returns as Accuracy so something like...

```
SELECT Order No., Deliverydate FROM orders WHERE Order No. = "1234" then (SubQuery) As Accuracy
```

**Query Result**

```
Order No.   Delivery Date   Accuracy
1234        6/20/2014         70%
```

So the Sub query/queries need to match the forecasts then return the divided quantity as a new column.

Comment: Is this SQL server or MS access ? If SQL server, then which version ?

Comment: I am using MS Access I guess I should take out sql-server tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be way after the fact...

Using the field names in the original question:

```
Select f.orderNo
, f.deliveryDate
, format(a.quantity/f.quantity, 'Percent') as accuracy
From (Select * from tbl_Orders where type='forecast') f
Inner Join (Select * from tbl_Orders where type='actual') a on f.orderNo = a.orderNo
```

This was done in MS Access 2010

Answer (score 0):

I made a query for SQL server. Let me know if it works for MS Access -

```
select orderno, deliverydate, Forecast, [Order], 
convert(decimal(5,2), ([Order]*100.0) / Forecast)  as Accuracy
from
(
select orderno, deliverydate, quantity, [type]
from Orders
) as src
pivot(
max(quantity)
for [type] in ([Forecast],[Order])
)as pvt
```

**For MS Access (what I have so far) -**

**I have never used MS Access**. But, I tried to make the MS Access query using the example given here - [TRANSFORM and PIVOT in Access 2013 SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691853/transform-and-pivot-in-access-2013-sql). Let me know if that works for you.

So your actual column names are different from what you gave. The queries based on those columns names are given below.

[image]

Create a query called queryPivot -

```
TRANSFORM Max(Quantity)
SELECT UPC, RDDto
FROM order_signals
GROUP BY UPC, RDDto
PIVOT [Type];
```

Create another query called querySelectFromPivot -

```
SELECT queryPivot.UPC, queryPivot.RDDto,
(queryPivot.Actual * 100.0/ queryPivot.Forecast) as 'Accuracy'
FROM queryPivot;
```

This is where I am stuck. It gives me blank values due to the missing values in your sample data. I tried to select just Actual * 100.0 instead, but that does not give me 
any decimal values. So, try to find out how to convert a column to decimal form. After that this query should work. (Man...access is so unintuitive for sql folks.)

Comment: PS - I never worked with MS Access. I wonder why it is still used now.

Comment: Employees in Large companies outside of IT

Comment: @user2625177 - The key concept is `PIVOT`, regardless of the database you use. Find out how to do pivot here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691853/transform-and-pivot-in-access-2013-sql Please post your solution when done. See how it is quite similar to my SQL query. I am trying to create a MS Acces query by looking at the example. Try it and let me know if that worked too. Good luck.

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately, can you explain your second line and why is [order] in brackets?

Comment: @user2625177 - the first query won't work because its an sql server query. Try the second one and let me know if it works or not. If you get an error, post the error here.

Comment: I got that 'Order' is not a recognized field or expression. Could you explain how I should match the two rows?

Comment: @user2625177 - To make things easier, can you upload your little MS Access database with just 2 rows to dropbox or skydrive or google drive ? I could download it from there and try it on my system. I have access in my system, but I never used it. I'll be back in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @user2625177 - hmm... my antivirus says that some of the content on that link is malicious. I did get the accdb file though. Please use standard services like sky drive, google etc instead of these random hosting services.

Answer (score 0):

So first I did a Join Called Central Query then created a query using that query.

So first I create two Queries, one for Forecasts (test) and one for just orders (Join-test)

So I join the two queries on the Deliver Date (RDD), Customer, and UPC and That is called from "Central Query"

Then I take the Quantities from Central Accuracy and Divide them here is the code.

Part 1 (there is another query that gets just signals (forecasts)

```
SELECT Customer, RDD, UPC, Shipto, Quantity, Type
FROM order_signals
WHERE Type = 'Order' AND RDD < NOW();
```

Use the two Queries to create "Central Query"

```
SELECT test.Customer, [Join-test].Customer, test.Quantity, [Join-test].Quantity, [Join-test].UPC, [Join-test].UPC, [Join-test].RDD
FROM test INNER JOIN [Join-test] ON (test.RDD = [Join-test].RDD) AND (test.Customer = [Join-test].Customer) AND (test.UPC = [Join-test].UPC);
```

Then I use the columns from central Query and I'm good!

```
SELECT [Central Query].[Join-test].Customer, [Central Query].UPC, [Central Query].test.Quantity, [Central Query].[Join-test].Quantity, Format(1-Abs(([Central Query].[Join-test].Quantity-[Central Query].test.Quantity)/[Central Query].test.Quantity),"Percent") AS Accuracy, [Central Query].RDD
FROM [Central Query];
```