# SQL Join operation in multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables in MS Access as follow:

```
--Students(ID, Name, Class)
--Subjects (ID, Name)
--Marks (ID, StudentID, Subject.ID)
```

Relation is as follow:

```
Marks.Subject = Subjects.ID
Marks.StudentID = Students.ID
```

Please Help me write a query that can return Name of Students and All SubjectNames and Marks of that student.

Currently I have this query but it returns marks separately.

```
select Students.Name, Marks.Obtained, Subjects.Name from Marks
inner join Students on Marks.StudentName = Students.ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have joined `students` and `marks` table with that Join `Subjects` table too

```
SELECT students.NAME, 
       marks.obtained, 
       subjects.NAME 
FROM  ( marks 
       INNER JOIN students 
               ON marks.studentname = students.id )
       INNER JOIN subjects 
               ON marks.subject = subjects.id
```

Comment: It says "Syntax Error(Missing Operator) in Query expression "Marks.StudentName = Students.ID
       JOIN Subjects 
         ON Marks.Subject = Subjects.I".

Comment: @TariqAbdullah - Check now. looks like Ms access does support `join` it should be `Inner Join`

Comment: @TariqAbdullah - Updated check now. My bad am not good at Ms access syntax

Comment: @TariqAbdullah - Looks like Access requires parentheses in the FROM clause for queries which include more than one join.

Comment: this:SELECT Students.Name, 
       Marks.Obtained, 
       Subjects.Name
FROM  (Marks 
       INNER JOIN Students 
               ON Marks.StudentName = Students.ID
       INNER JOIN Subjects 
         ON Marks.Subject = Subjects.ID)

does not work

Comment: @TariqAbdullah it is not same as my answer. Did you try my updated answer

Comment: Thanks NoDisplayName. It works but It still returns subject name in addition to what I already have .. How can it be grouped by Name showing name of subject as column and Marks its as value

Comment: @TariqAbdullah - That is another question dude. you have to ask a new question

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am highly obliged. Thanks again.

Comment: BTW, Can you help me with this?

Comment: @TariqAbdullah Sorry man am not good in MS ACCESS. I am a `SQL SERVER` guy since this a basic question i just tried

Comment: @TariqAbdullah - check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546305/pivoting-data-in-ms-access and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691853/transform-and-pivot-in-access-2013-sql

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select Students.Name, Marks.Obtained, Subjects.Name from Marks
inner join Students on Marks.Subject = Subjects.ID
Marks.StudentID = Students.ID
```

Comment: What is `Subjects` in this query?

Answer (score 0):

```
This will help you : 



 select Students.Name, Marks.Obtained, Subjects.Name from Marks
    inner join Students on Marks.StudentName = Students.ID
    inner join Subjects on Marks.Subject = Subjects.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.name, b.obtained, c.name
FROM studentTable a
INNER JOIN marksTable b ON a.ID = b.StudentID
INNER JOIN subjectsTable c ON b.Subject.ID = c.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I would reorder this as follows:

```
select A1.Name as 'Student Name'
  , A3.Name as 'Subject'
  , A2.Obtained as 'Mark Obtained' 
from Students AS A1  
     inner join Marks as A2 on A1.ID = A2.StudentID
     inner join Subjects AS A3 on A2.Subject = A3.ID GO;
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: does it become "select Students.Name as 'Student Name', Marks.Obtained as 'Mark Obtained', Subjects.Name as 'Subject' 
from Students AS Students  
inner join Marks as Marks on Students.ID = Marks.StudentName
inner join Subjects AS Subjects on Marks.Subject = Marks.ID GO;"??

Comment: Are you writing this in SSMS or Access?

Comment: I am writing this in Access

Comment: SELECT Students.Name, Marks.Obtained, Subjects.Name
FROM Students INNER JOIN (Marks INNER JOIN Subjects ON Marks.Subject = Subjects.ID) ON Students.ID = Marks.StudentID
GROUP BY Students.Name, Marks.Obtained, Subjects.Name;

Comment: It works but the data is separated. Not grouped by name. It is just slight extension of what I already have .. since this query returns only name of subject in addition. what i need is that subject name should be treated as a column and marks of a particular student be displayed as column value.

Comment: Then there must be an error with your joins - I'd question this: Marks.Subject = Subjects.ID
Marks.StudentID = Students.ID You also noted a column name in Marks as Subject.ID, but that doesn't conform to Access object naming rules. Check the fields you're joining on.

Comment: It works but the data is separated. Not grouped by name. It is just slight extension of what I already have .. since this query returns only name of subject in addition. what i need is that subject name should be treated as a column and marks of a particular student be displayed as column value

Comment: SELECT Students.Name, Subjects.Name, Marks.Obtained
FROM Students INNER JOIN (Marks INNER JOIN Subjects ON Marks.Subject = Subjects.ID) ON Students.ID = Marks.StudentID
GROUP BY Students.Name, Subjects.Name, Marks.Obtained;