# I have a table that looks like:

Tags: ms-access, unpivot

I have a table that has

```
     Material   90    89     88    87    ….2     1     0
      123456    34    30     26    38     14    12     8
      123457    47    42     33    54     38    27    42
```

And I want to convert it to

```
     Date        123456     123457              
    Date()-90       34         47
    Date()-89       30         42
    Date()-88       26         33
    Date()-87       38         54
       ….        …………        ………..
    Date()-2        14         38
    Date()-1        12         27
    Date()           8         42
```

I found this, but am trying to figure out how to use it:

```
Private Sub Unpivot_Click()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim columncount As Integer
    Dim setRST As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sqlstr As String
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field

    Set setRST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from TheTable")
columncount = setRST.Fields.Count
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef ("", "Insert Into TheDestination ([Template], [Row], 
[Column], [Result]) VALUES (@Template, @RowNumber, @ColumnNumber, @Result)")
Do While Not setRST.EOF
   qdf.Parameters("@Template") = setRST!Template
   qdf.Parameters("@RowNumber") = setRST!row
   For Each fld In setRST.Fields
       If IsNumeric(fld.Name) Then
            qdf.Parameters("@ColumnNumber") = fld.Name
            qdf.Parameters("@Result") = fld.Value
            qdf.Execute 
       End If
      Next fld
      setRST.MoveNext
   Loop

End Sub
```

So far, I have:

```
Public Function Unpivot()

Dim x As Integer
Dim columncount As Integer
Dim setRST As DAO.Recordset
Dim sqlstr As String
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field

Set setRST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SSMaterialByDayQ322")
columncount = setRST.Fields.Count
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", "Insert INTO SSHistoryQ322 ([Date], [Row], [Column], [Result]) VALUES (@Template, @RowNumber, @ColumnNumber, @Result)")
Do While Not setRST.EOF
   qdf.Parameters("@Template") = setRST!Date
   qdf.Parameters("@RowNumber") = setRST!row
   For Each fld In setRST.Fields
       If IsNumeric(fld.Name) Then
            qdf.Parameters("@ColumnNumber") = fld.Name
            qdf.Parameters("@Result") = fld.Value
            qdf.Execute
       End If
   Next fld
   setRST.MoveNext
Loop

End Function
```

Comment: So--What is the question?  What message on what line are you getting, or what do the results look like?  What are the values when that message appears?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to transpose rows into columns in ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593728/i-want-to-transpose-rows-into-columns-in-ms-access)

Comment: For more duplicates, google *access query transpose*

Comment: I doubt creating/modifying query with QueryDefs will achieve this. You need to save data to a table. How many values of Material are possible? Table has a limit of 255 fields.

Comment: on the Set qdf = db.createquerydef("", "insert into.... I get Object Required.

Comment: I have about 1800 material plant combinations, but can manage by plant to limit the number of materials in each transposed table to less than 254

Comment: @user3470177 you might try  dim db as database   and  set db = currentdb in order to create the Object Required

Answer (score 0):

If there are not more than 50 fields in the table needing to be 'unpivoted', a UNION query can rearrange the data to a normalized structure. There is no query builder or wizard for UNION, must type or copy/paste in SQL view. UNION has limit of 50 SELECT lines.

```
SELECT "Date()-90" AS [Date], Material, [90] AS Data FROM SSMaterialByDayQ322
UNION SELECT "Date()-89", Material, [89] FROM SSMaterialByDayQ322
UNION SELECT "Date()-88", Material, [88] FROM SSMaterialByDayQ322
UNION SELECT "Date()-87", Material, [87] FROM SSMaterialByDayQ322
UNION SELECT "Date()-2", Material, [2] FROM SSMaterialByDayQ322
UNION SELECT "Date()-1", Material, [1] FROM SSMaterialByDayQ322
UNION SELECT "Date()-0", Material, [0] FROM SSMaterialByDayQ322;
```

If there are more than 50 year fields, VBA can write records to table, consider:

```
Public Sub Unpivot()
Dim x As Integer
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SSMaterialByDayQ322")
Do While Not rst.EOF
   For x = 1 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO SSHistoryQ322([Date], Material, Data)" & _
                          "VALUES('Date()-" & rst.Fields(x).Name & "', " & rst!Material & ", " & rst.Fields(x) & ")"
   Next
   rst.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

Then as long as there aren't more than 254 unique Material values, build CROSSTAB from the query or table.

```
TRANSFORM First(Query1.Data) AS FirstOfData
SELECT Query1.Date
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.Date
PIVOT Query1.Material;
```

Recommend not using Date as a field name because it is a reserved word.

Comment: the date()-90, date()-89....date()-2, date()-1, date() implies that there are 91 columns values for each row.  Last I tried a union, the limit was indeed 50, plus it's very slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by making a union query

```
SELECT 'Date()-90' As [Date], Material, [90] As [Value] FROM TheTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Date()-89' As [Date], Material, [89] As [Value] FROM TheTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Date()-88' As [Date], Material, [88] As [Value] FROM TheTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Date()-87' As [Date], Material, [87] As [Value] FROM TheTable
...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Date()-02' As [Date], Material, [2] As [Value] FROM TheTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Date()-01' As [Date], Material, [1] As [Value] FROM TheTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Date()-00' As [Date], Material, [0] As [Value] FROM TheTable
```

Of course, you can use VBA to create this query in a loop. Store this SQL-Text as query `qryFlatten`.

Now we build a pivot query from this query. This yields our final result

```
TRANSFORM Sum(qryFlatten.Value) AS SumOfValue
SELECT qryFlatten.Date
FROM qryFlatten
GROUP BY qryFlatten.Date
ORDER BY qryFlatten.Date DESC 
PIVOT qryFlatten.Material;
```