# Display records as columns and fields as rows.

Tags: ms-access, datatables

Can i do it in Access 2016?

I have a scheduling aid that displays the dates as columns and personnel as rows in excel. The problem is the field restriction set by access, and i cant auto generate fields like i can records. Is it possible to flip the view. I dont want to change the functionality, just the view. Ive tried crosstab query but they arent editable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to transpose rows into columns in ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593728/i-want-to-transpose-rows-into-columns-in-ms-access)

Comment: But any query you use to get a transposed view will be read-only. You'll have to restructure your source data.

Comment: Andre, while possible, i am afraid that is not very practicle. I need dates as my fields but the field limit is 225 or there about. It would be nice to generate a year at a time. I have an a day rotation so I could make seperate tables. The problem with that is that sometimes we use a 4 day rotation and we need to see all the data together. I am trying to keep it very simple for the users. And keep the database small. Im not trying to transpose (i dont think) i dont want to turn the rows into fields, i just want to view them as such.

Comment: Data should be saved in normalized structure then manipulated to 'other views' for display.