# Access 2010 input second returned value into query result

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am building a query that looks for a contract number in a second table of which there will be multiple results. But what i want to do is instead of returning a second row i want it to look like below

Contract No |  Result 1  |  Result 2  |  Result 3

rather than

contract no | result 1

contract no | result 2

contract no | result 3

How to do this?

The concatrelated vb is not a viable option for us within the business that i work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine values from related rows into a single concatenated string value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278590/combine-values-from-related-rows-into-a-single-concatenated-string-value)

Comment: It sounds like you need to pivot the results of the second query - look here and see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546305/pivoting-data-in-ms-access

Comment: I gave in and used the concatenate vb script but i would like to be able to limit the to only concatenate the first 3 results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pivoting data in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546305/pivoting-data-in-ms-access)