# SQL Query for Pivoting data in MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with three fields: ticketNumber, attendee and tableNumber.

e.g.

```
ticketNumber | attendee | tableNumber
------------ | -------- | -----------
     A1      | alex     |     3  
     A2      | bret     |     2  
     A3      | chip     |     1  
     A4      | dale     |     2  
     A5      | eric     |     2  
     A6      | finn     |     3
```

I'd like to generate a table with each tableNumber as a field and the list of names sitting at that tableNumber.

```
  1  |  2   | 3
-----|------|-----
chip | bret | alex 
     | dale | finn
     | eric |
```

The query I've been working on is:

```
transform attendee
select attendee
from registration
group by tableNumber, name
pivot tableNumber
```

This gives me:

```
attendee |  1   |  2   |  3 
---------|------|------|----- 
chip     | chip |      | 
bret     |      | bret |
dale     |      | dale |
eric     |      | eric |
alex     |      |      | alex
finn     |      |      | finn
```

I know how to get the table I require using PivotTableView but I'd like to know how to do it with a query so that I can use it in a code I'm working on. I'm unsure of how I can write this query without having to select a field (in my case, select attendee). Also is it possible to generate the table without the empty cells?

Thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pivoting data in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546305/pivoting-data-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table needs a unique identifier field that will properly sort and I don't think the ticketNumber can be relied on for that. An autonumber should serve. Then try:

`TRANSFORM First(Table1.attendee) AS FirstOfattendee
SELECT DCount("*","Table1","tableNumber=" & [tableNumber] & " AND ID<" & [ID])+1 AS RowSeq
FROM Table1
GROUP BY DCount("*","Table1","tableNumber=" & [tableNumber] & " AND ID<" & [ID])+1
PIVOT Table1.tableNumber;`