# Access SQL - Select same column twice for different criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been struggling with the following table for a while now. Hopefully anyone can help me out.

```
Item  Type  Value
A     X     2
B     X     3
C     X     4
D     X     5
A     Y     0.1
B     Y     0.3
C     Y     0.4
D     Y     0.6
```

The result I would like to see is this:

```
Item  X     Y
A     2     0.1
B     3     0.3
C     4     0.4
D     5     0.6
```

Is it possible to fix this in one query?
I tried Union queries and IIF statements, but none of it gives me the desired result. Another option might be to split it up in multiple queries, however I would rather have it done in once.

Looking forward to any answer.

Many thanks!

Best,

Mathijs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pivoting data in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546305/pivoting-data-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a job for a Crosstab query.

```
TRANSFORM Max(Table1.Valu) AS MaxOfValu
SELECT Table1.item
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.item
PIVOT Table1.type;
```

ps: `Value` is a reserved word and cannot be used as a field name. And I would never used `Type` or `Item` either.

Comment: Awesome Patrick, thanks. I'll try it out. Yes, I know I just made up some dummy data here.