# Access Pivot SQL Grouped by multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table and want to create a new table with the data pivoted.

```
[report date] [Name] [Location] [Desc] [Value]
1/1/2017 Bob Spain Sales 10
1/1/2017 Bob Spain Costs 5
2/1/2017 Bob Spain Sales 20
2/1/2017 Bob Spain Costs 8
1/1/2017 Tom Spain Sales 9
1/1/2017 Tom Spain Costs 4
2/1/2017 Tom Spain Sales 19
2/1/2017 Tom Spain Costs 7
```

And would like to use Access VBA SQL to pivot the data as follows:

```
[Report Date] [Name] [Location] [Sales] [Costs]
1/1/2017 Bob Spain 10 5
2/1/2017 Bob Spain 20 8
1/1/2017 Tom Spain  9 4
2/1/2017 Tom Spain 19 7
```

I see a lot of examples of how to pivot with just 3 columns e.g.; `[Report Date] [Desc] [Value]`. [Pivoting data in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546305/pivoting-data-in-ms-access) How can the other attribute columns be carried along?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Select 
    [report date], 
    [Name],
    [Location],
    Sum(IIf([Desc] = 'Sales', [Value], 0)) As Sales,
    Sum(IIf([Desc] = 'Costs', [Value], 0)) As Costs
From
    YourTable
Group By
    [Name],
    [Location],
    [report date]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I can not see any PIVOT expression on your suggested answer

Comment: @masoudabrishami: Not needed for only two fixed columns. See attached output, please.

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify the other columns in `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses of MS Access's crosstab query which contains an aggregate query nested within:

```
TRANSFORM MAX([Value])
SELECT [Report Date], [Name], [Location]
FROM myTable
GROUP BY [Report Date], [Name], [Location]
PIVOT [Desc];
```