# SQL Query to transpose rows to columns in MS Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using MS Access DB it has a table named ‘tssStockMaster’ with fields (PartNo, ItemName,Stock,Workshop) as shown in the image with following data.

[image: table : tssStockMaster with data]

Now I am unable to write a query in MS Access Database using SQL to get the following output such that the stock quantity is shown for each workshops against each item name(group by PartNo).

[image: Required Output using SQL query in ms access database]

Since we cant use PIVOT in MS Access how can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can use the _crosstab query wizard_ to get started.

Comment: Can you use TRANSFORM? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546305/pivoting-data-in-ms-access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know up front how many workshops will be there and the number isn't significant I bet you could use aggregate function with if conditions:

```
select 
    partno
  , itemname
  , sum(iif(workshop = 'W101', stock, 0)) as w101
  , sum(iif(workshop = 'Z239', stock, 0)) as z239
from t
group by partno, itemname
```